# Hosting service on differnt machine and same machine

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

in interview a guy set a scenario  and ask me the difference but i was unable to answer that question,,, so i am asking same question here....

i Have two (web or wcf) services.  one service is on another server and second service is on the same server where my web application is deployed and consuming both services he ask me that what is the difference of one service on another server and one service on same server,,,is that thing make any difference ????

please  help me out on this query that what make the difference of one service on same server where application is there and second is on other server and application consuming both service..????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Within same server you can use net.pipe binding
2. Within same server it will be faster, because you save time on traffic